# Check if an arraylist has values from a predefined range of values only

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist which has String values which may be duplicated too, no issues there.
Also, I have a pre-defined range/options of those values, which are allowed.An arraylist having allowed values, but I can use any datastructure if I get my probem solved.

I just need a way to make sure my arraylist has no alien values, if so, it POINTS OUT which index number if faulty or are faulty if multiple.

I have tried .contains() method and many others, but I can't get the Faulty index position.

I am ready to use any datastructure or any method, but need that FAULTY INDEX NUMBER.

FYI, I am using java and the arraylist has values from a ResultSet.

Comment: Could you provide an example as well?

Comment: What is faulty for you?

Comment: Use a for loop. If the current element doesn't match the range, return the current index. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: current_arraylist : a,d,b,c
allowed values : a,b,c
result: index number 2 is faulty !

Comment: is for loop okay if I have to check 40k+ values ??

Comment: for loop is ok for infinite list given that your sistem can accomodate the resources :)

Comment: How else would you do that without looping through the elements? Note that indices start at 0, not 1.

Comment: @JBNizet I tried using a nested for loop,but aint successful, which arraylist should be on the outer for loop ?

Comment: There is no way to check each element without, well... checking each element. The best you can do is a for loop, and check each element's validity with something like `allowed.contains(value)`. You may want to consider making `allowed` a `Set`.

Comment: But I have to iterate both arraylists, I am not getting the way to do that, viz the implementation part !

Comment: That’s what contains and indexOf will do behind the scenes. Since you want each position where the dupe occurs, you need to use a for loop.

Comment: If you have nested for loops, you're not splitting the problem into simpler pieces. Start by writing a method which checks if **one** value is in the range. Then use a loop and call that method for each element of the list.

Comment: I'll try, thanks, and I have been trying before posting the ques, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that there is always a **better approach** to things, but I somehow solved this (please ignore approach as answer is exactly what I wanted).

I had 2 arraylists A and B and I wanted to know which element of A(Allowed+faulty values) is not in B(allowed values) **and most** **importantly** at which position.

What I did was :

--> Made an arraylist A_temp viz a copy of A.(same elements as A).

--> Used A.removeAll(B).
 This made my A contain only error values(which is what I wanted to point to).

--> Finally, I printed out A_temp.indexOf(A.get(index)).

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do a this task using set (based this on your comment example with string):

```
List <String> all = ...
Set <String> allowed = ..

for(String current : all){
   if(!allowed.contains(current){
      // out of range
   }
}
```

This approach is faster w.r.t the one which iterates both lists linearly taking advantage of optimized search in a set data structure.

Comment: yupp, as I said, any datastructure is OK, will try, thanks everyone!

Comment: for(String current : o_branch_id){
      if(!setta.contains(current)){
  System.out.println("faulty index is : index "+o_branch_id.indexOf(current));
      }
   }


I used this, it is returning wrong indexes, that too multiple times,viz, the values are fine and inside the allowed set !!

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you want. It might not be the optimized way to do this, but you can get some idea form this

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> valuesList = Arrays.asList("aa", "bb", "bb", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee", "ff", "gg");
        List<String> correctValues = Arrays.asList("bb", "dd", "ff");

        List wrongPositions = getPositions(valuesList, correctValues);
    }

    static List getPositions(List<String> values, List<String> correctValues) {

        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
            numbers.add(i);
        }

        List<Integer> correctPositions = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String correctValue : correctValues) {
            while (values.indexOf(correctValue) > -1) {
                correctPositions.add(values.indexOf(correctValue));
                values.set(values.indexOf(correctValue), "SomeValueNotContainingInList");
            }
        }

        numbers.removeAll(correctPositions);
        return numbers;
    }
}
```